# How to type a NORMAL tilde sign (~) in Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have switched to macOS recently. The only thing that's disturbing me now is the missing the tilde sign (~). The closest thing I achieved to this sign is the accent tilde (˜). This accent tilde won't work with my current passwords.

I'm using a U.S International PC keyboard layout.

How do I make the tilde sign work on my Mac?

Comment: What about hardware? Are you using a Mac style keyboard? Or your old PC style keyboard?

Comment: $3000 laptop and it can't handle typing, it can't properly connect to APs, it can't delete char at right, it can't have both function keys and multimedia keys at the same time... I am switching back to PC with Linux

Comment: The amount of answers and comments to a question about how to type a single character made me lol so hard! Don't get me wrong, I have a Macbook and two Apple keyboards so I feel your pain.

Comment: For US Keyboard I use Control + ` + Enter

Comment: The only thing that ended up working for me was rebinding the key using Karabiner-Elements...

Answer (score 84):

You type the accent tilde (shift `) then space: ~

Comment: I have to do Option + n to get the little tilde, but Shift + the key under ESC only displays ±. I'm used to the PC formats which do as you suggested (without the extra space), but it's not the case on my Mac.

Comment: Then it is shift + the key to the left of z.  Is ` not marked on that?

Comment: `Alt + n` then space gives me ˜. shift ` gives me ±.

Comment: @ThomasAhle What is the name of the Input Source you are using?  These instructions are for US International PC.

Comment: That's the one. On Sierra. I also tried all other English qwerty layouts with similar luck. Eventually I found out the button between shift and Z works.

Comment: @ThomasAhle Still, if you see the US flag with the little pc underneath in the top right corner of your screen, then Option n plus space should always give you ~., like it does for me here.

Comment: I meant Alt. Option + N gives me a new window in most programs.

Comment: @ThomasAhle You seem to be confusing those keys.  Alt and Option are the same key.  New window is Command n (⌘ n).  Alt/Option n plus space should produce ~.

Comment: you are amazing, sir

Comment: Is there a way to disable this behaviour? I never use the accent tilde for example.

Comment: @FelixCrazzolara Just use the US input source instead of US International PC.

Comment: I wonder if they could even make it harder to find :)

Comment: finally, a solution :D

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find this mode of typing a normal tilde utterly unacceptable for people working in a console (a terminal emulator).

Comment: @sequence then get rid of us international pc and replace it with the abc or us input source

Comment: @TomGewecke Tried it, it's all the same on my Mac for the tilde. It's still § or ± there.

Comment: @sequence  then ~ is on the key between Z and left shift.  If you do not have such a key, then your machine mistakenly thinks your keyboard is ISO instead of ANSI and you need to change the Keyboard Type

Answer (score 49):

You might consider switching "U.S. International **PC** layout" to "U.S. layout"
[image]

Comment: There is no need to do that.

Comment: I've tried what you said, but even the U.S layout gives me § without shift and ± with a shift press. Suggestions?

Comment: It's probably on the key that located between `Shift` and `Z`. Make sure you have "Show Input menu in the Menu bar" selected, and open `Keyboard viewer` from the menu bar to see you keyboard.

Comment: On MacBook Pro with norwegian keyboard: type  `Alt+^`..

Comment: Thanks, this is great help! I never need an superseced tilde but always need the home symbol. Even in scientific work, I will use \tilde instead

Comment: @aborted, I had the same behavior.
For the `~` symbol to be under ESC with the US layout, the keyboard type must be set to "ANSI" (as of BigSur: preferences > keyboard > Change Keyboard Type...).
Having the keyboard type set to "ISO" will yeld the result you describe - § without shift and ± with a shift press.

I can only assume this happens when the keyboard detected by MacOS is non-us (I use a European layout).

Answer (score 29):

On my Czech keyboard when using the U.S. input source it works to use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+`/` (button next to <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>, see the screenshot). I believe the same button is above the enter key on MacBooks from other countries.

When using the Czech input source with this keyboard, ~ is gotten via <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> (where it is printed on the key).

[image: MacBook keyboard]
[image: keyboard preferences]

Comment: The question is about the US International PC layout.  Plus your answer is already covered by the one from Sergei.

Comment: This answer helped

Comment: You saved me a lot of headaches!

Comment: ~ Only correct answer ~

Comment: This works for me on macOS Ventura 13.3.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

On a French, Spanish or German Mac keyboard,
type <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to write the `~` character then space for normal tilde or n for tilde over n.

Comment: This worked for me in German keyboard on Mac.

Answer (score 9):

On a Finnish Mac keyboard layout (probably applies to some other international keyboard layouts as well) the tilde can be produced with the key with the symbols <kbd>^¨</kbd>. That is on the left side of <kbd>Enter</kbd> and below the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key.

When pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>^¨</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd> the tilde `~` appears.

Comment: Didn't work in Minecraft + Finnish Mac keyboard, unfortunately.

Comment: This also applies to the Danish layout.

Comment: No space needed, only cmd + ^

Answer (score 5):

For those readers who want to make tilde accents over characters instead of the NORMAL tilde sign (~) requested by Aborted, here is some possibly useful info:

<kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> applies a `~` to the next `a`, `o`, or `n` that you type (given that you release them first). In the event that your keyboard/keyboard settings do not afford you the character,  more modified character options are available in the keyboard preferences option available from the toolbar in the upper right corner.
[image: keyboardOptionsTab]
select "Latin" from the option on the left, then double click on your desired character to insert at your cursor.
[image: characterOptions]
Another option is the Accent Menu you get when you hold down the key for the base letter, as described by Apple [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25643)

Answer (score 5):

In the Spanish keyboard, press and hold the <kbd>⌥ Option/Alt</kbd> key and hit "ñ".

Answer (score 4):

On my MacBook with Italian keyboard layout it works with <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>.

This is tilde as in "~", ASCII 126, that can be used for example in Linux CLI.

<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> followed by <kbd>Space</kbd> produces the diacritic tilde : "˜"

That looks similar, but it's actually smaller and shifted upwards and is not the tilde ASCII but rather Unicode 0303 combining diacritic tilde https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0303

Answer (score 1):

I just pressed all bottons and found that if you press <kbd>⌥ Option/Alt</kbd> + <kbd>¨</kbd> you will get `~`.

Comment: This works on my Danish keyboard layout :)

Answer (score 0):

The U.S International PC keyboard layout was the issue for me, as well as similar issues for other symbols (different versions of ^, and auto options for ' and " that I didn't want). Keyboard shortcuts were ineffective with this layout too, always outputting accent hildes. Changing to the Australian keyboard worked for me, and [U.S. layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/135141/278085) works too. Other types of keyboards should work too, though based from the other answers, the output for hilde (and also for other symbols) varies across different types of keyboards.

Answer (score -3):

Try using Shift+Page Down. I don't know Apple keyboard layout (I'm using a Hackintosh) but it works for me.

Answer (score -4):

Try 
hold option key down and type n
release option key and type n again   ñ

Comment: But the question is how to type tilde ~, not how to type ñ.  You should delete this answer since it makes it look like you failed to read the question.